# Computable numbers

Tags: computer-science, computability

In Barry Cooper's "Computability theory" there is an exercise (16.4.12 to be precise) which I can't find anyway to do it... it states:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Define

$$r_A=\sum_{i \in A} 2^{-i}$$

Prove that $r_A$ is computable if, and only if, $A$ is computable. I'm having trouble understanding the notion of modulus of convergence, so I don't know how to prove the statement "if $A$ is computable, then $r_A$ is computable". Do I have to use Church-Turing thesis?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to say more about the definitions given in the book: the definition I would give of "computable real" does not explicitly use the term "modulus of convergence". The Church-Turing thesis isn't a method of proof.

Comment: The definition he uses for computable real is that it must be a sequence of rational numbers such that $|q_i - q_j| \leq 2^{-n}$.

Comment: The direction you asked about seems to be the easier one. Given an algorithm for deciding membership in $A$, you can approximate $r_A$ with any prescribed accuracy, say $2^{-n}$ by checking which of $0,1,\dots,n+1$ are in $A$ and using $\sum_{i\in A\cap\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}}2^{-i}$ as your approximation.

Comment: The converse is more fiddly and less satisfactory, as you have to allow for the fact that you can have $A$ and $B$ with $r_A  = r_B$ (.e.g, $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$). However that only happens if one of $A$ and $B$ is finite and the other is the complement of a finite set.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I got it.

Comment: Now you've got it, why not write up the answer here!

Comment: Sure! So, if $A$ is computable, then there is an algorithm which decides what elements belong to $A$. So we can decide if each element of the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ is or is not in $A$. Choosing the accuracy to be $2^{-n}$, we therefore have the following sequence of computable rational numbers: $\sum_{i \in A \cap \{1, \dots, n\}} 2^{-i}$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This sequence converges to $r_A$, since we can exhaust all elements of $A$, for $A$ is computable.

Comment: But then we have a sequence of rationals such that the difference of any two consecutive elements of it is less than or equal to the chosen accuracy, $2^{-n}$. Thus, by definition of computable number, $r_A$ is computable. Is it okay?

Comment: *sequence of rationals converging to $r_A$. such that ... above!

Comment: Your proposed answer looks good for the "if" part. How about "only if"?

Comment: The "only if" part I don't know how to do it... When I said I got it I meant the part I asked in the question...

Comment: But I will try: if $r_A$ is computable, then $\sum_{i \in A} 2^{-i}$ is also computable. This means we have an algorithm to compute this sum. But we can only compute it if we have an effective procedure to decide which elements are in $A$, for else we can't decide if $i \in A$ or not, and thus can't compute the summation. In fact, the algorithm that computes $r_A$ has to decide which $i$ is in  and which isn't. Therefore for the sum to be computable, $A$ must be computable too.